# Google's File Insert v2 API fails to recognise MIME TYPE application/vnd.google-apps.document

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, mime-types, drive, google-drive-realtime-api

This morning, I tried using Google APIs File Insert where I provided MIME TYPE as application/vnd.google-apps.document.

I am getting the following response from Google API

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&alt=json returned "Invalid mime type provided">
```

I replaced MIME TYPE `application/vnd.google-apps.document` with `application/msword` and the API started working. Has anything changed with Google API?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, trying to use a mimetype of application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet when uploading a CSV has worked for years, until today. I hope this is not a permanent change

Comment: I tried with both v2 and v3 APIs and I am getting the same results. Very strange. Google Drive API has not mentioned any outage or change on their website as well.

Comment: Alright, looks like Google fixed this issue. It's working for me now. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google reported there was an outage

```
https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=4&iid=11e934443f5863c5b46aa779c36ff4d3
```